# Maven compile showing fixed error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am using maven 3.0.5, using that i have created a web app project and now trying to compile it. 
First time while running mvn clean install. I found some error, I have fixed them and now trying to compile again but it still showing me same errors.

Initially i found error in my code. Error is

required Map> found Map> But I have fixed this in my code

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? There's not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Initially i found error in my code. its 
required Map<String LinkedHashMap<string,object>>
found Map<String Map<string,object>>
But I have fixed this in my code

Comment: clean one more time and then try to build project

Answer (score 0):

**please try**

1) Try once with **changed work-space**.

2) **Check** if **classpath** are given correctly.

3) **Check** if **required jars** are present.

4) **Use same version of Jars**, there must **not be duplicate jars of different versions** .

5) While writing Question **please give the code** and when you say i fixed it **please provide** **what you did to fix**, so that we can have better understanding of your problem.